# Exclude images from lightbox in "Photo Swipe Masonry"

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, photoswipe

i am using the "Photo Swipe Masonry" plugin (version 1.0.6) on wordpress 4.3.1.
It works perfect so far.

But, i have some images which have a custom link to an external url(instead of the stadard to the image).  If i click one of these images, it opens the url in a new window. That works like expected.
Now, when i click on an standard image(**no external url**), the lightbox opens and the image is displayed like expected.

But now, when i use the prev/next buttons to navigate through the images and i reach an **image with a custom link**, i got the errormessage:

"*The image could not be loaded"* (in the lightbox).

So, my question is, **how to exclude images from being added to the lightbox**?
Maybe by a unique class ?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance to all of you for your time.

Regards,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer of this plugin. Sorry for missing this post. There is no function built in for this sorry. You would need to edit the photoswipe code.

Comment: Is that still true as of 2021?